# How to check all values in object property same in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to check if array of object property has same value using javascript

If `cid` is same value in array of object, then return true.

note: cid is not always ad `109` might change

```js
var arrobj = [{"cid":109,"aid":220},{"cid":109,"aid":221}]

// I Tried

const result = arrobj.every(e => e.cid);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `const result = arrobj.every(e => e.cid === arrobj[0].cid);`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if every `cid` is equal to any other `cid` in your array (e. g. `arrayobj[0].cid`). If that's the case you know they are all equal regardless of their value.

```
arrobj.every(e => e.cid === arrobj[0].cid);
```

---

This is how you could do it iterating manually using a `for`:

```js
var arrobj = [
  {cid: 109, aid: 220},
  {cid: 109, aid: 221}
];

const sameCid = array => {
  let result = true;

  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].cid !== array[0].cid) {
      result = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(sameCid(arrobj));
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the cid property has the same value in an array of objects using JavaScript, you can iterate through the array and keep track of the unique cid values you encounter. If you find duplicate cid values, then you can return true. Here's how you can do it:

```js
function hasDuplicateCid(arr) {
    const cidSet = new Set();

    for (const obj of arr) {
        if (cidSet.has(obj.cid)) {
            return true;
        }
        cidSet.add(obj.cid);
    }

    return false;
}

const arrobj = [{"cid": 109, "aid": 220}, {"cid": 109, "aid": 221}];

const hasDuplicate = hasDuplicateCid(arrobj);
console.log(hasDuplicate); // Output: true
```

In this example, the hasDuplicateCid function iterates through the array of objects. It uses a Set to keep track of unique cid values. If it encounters a cid that already exists in the Set, it means there's a duplicate, and it returns true. Otherwise, if the loop completes without finding duplicates, it returns false.

You can adjust the function name and variable names to fit your codebase. ;)

Comment: This looks like a chatGPT answer. Those are [banned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the third argument of the `Array::every()`'s callback to access the array. That would be more a functional approach and more performant since the array is accessed directly without looking in the outer scope.

Also you could use argument destructuring to make the code a bit nicer:

```js
const arrobj = [{"cid":109,"aid":220},{"cid":109,"aid":221}]

const result = arrobj.every(({cid}, _, arr) => cid === arr[0].cid);
console.log(result);
```

If you want max speed you could use a `for` loop and skip the first element compared to itself:

```js
const arrobj = [{"cid":109,"aid":220},{"cid":109,"aid":221}]

let result = true;
for(let i = 1; i < arrobj.length; i++){
  if(arrobj[i].cid !== arrobj[0].cid){
    result = false;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="100000000">

const arrobj = [{"cid":109,"aid":220},{"cid":109,"aid":221}]

// @benchmark every
arrobj.every(item => item.cid === arrobj[0].cid);

// @benchmark Alexander every
arrobj.every(({cid}, _, arr) => cid === arr[0].cid);

// @benchmark for loop
let result = true;
for(let i = 1; i < arrobj.length; i++){
  if(arrobj[i].cid !== arrobj[0].cid){
    result = false;
    break;
  }
}
result;

</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```